# PGFplots - Imitate minimalistic style

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams

The style of plots, as shown in the example of a thesis I saw, can be found in literature of topics ranging from mechanical engineering to physics.

I am primarily interested to know if this is a specific style option or package (like using colorbrewer sets for colours). 
(If it is none of this, I will try to re-imagine it myself.)

So far, I have checked the TikZ Galery for any other examples of this and looked through math sans serif fonts, but it was not successful yet.

Just as an addition, the reason I am searching for a package or something similar, is that this style of diagram is fairly widespread. And not only do the axes look differently than regular pgfplots (see the dimensions for the percentage on the y-axis), there's also the different fontand the arrows in the axis description. These characteristics are always the same when these diagrams can be found in books which makes me think that this is a fundamental design.

[image: Example Diagram]

Comment: see `pgfplots` or `pstrick`.

Comment: You'll have to find out which font is used for the axes. Then through `pgfplots` or `pstricks`, it should not be too difficult.

Comment: There are two questions. (1) How to get such a layout? This is indeed rather easy with pgfplots. (2) Your plots seems to interpolate some data points. This certainly can be done with pgfplots as well if you have a clear prescription.

Comment: I am aware of pstricks and pgfplots (i thought including the tags would indicate it, but I'll make it clearer in the question). However, neither of these two includes depiction of dimensions like the percentage here, or the arrow or this specific font. I checked mathsf fonts but I havent found a similar one so far. I also looked through the TikZ Galery but was not successful so far. (These diagrams occur often enough, though, in this exact manner to indicate that this is a fundamental way of display.)

Comment: As long as you leave the question vague, i.e. just post a screen shot, there is a good chance that you only get vague comments instead of an answer. On the other hand, if you provide a code that produces the plots and the data points, I am very confident that someone will provide you with the axis styles.

Comment: Could you suggest a less vague way to phrase the question, if I indeed do not want source code that imitates this look but an answer if this is a certain, generic style template and if so, which.

Comment: @pogo-otter, you are right, this style can often be found in books. But I am not aware of the underlying style in general. But if you have a look at [DIN 461](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_461) this also seems to use this type of style. Unfortunately I am not aware of a "higher" norm like ISO that corresponds to the DIN.